# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none)

Tags: python, selenium, pip, webdriver

from selenium import webdriver

class IB:
    def **init**(self):
        browser = webdriver.chrome()
        browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

IB()
The error i'm getting is
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none)

> Blockquote

I have installed selenium perfectly (i guess so)
The IDE i'm using is PyCharm and it is fully updated as of June 2020
My pip is fully updated
Can someone please help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ns5N.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't install drivers for chrome, see section Drivers in https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html